# Official Facebook RSS feed for a Page

Tags: facebook, rss

Many people have described how to obtain the RSS data feed for a Facebook page.
For example: http://ahrengot.com/tutorials/facebook-rss-feed/

The following URL provides the feed for Coca-Cola's page:
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=40796308305

However, I cannot seem to find any documentation on facebook.com that describes this interface.  Does anyone know if this interface is officially supported by Facebook?  I don't want to reference it in my code only to have it dropped unexpectedly by Facebook.

I know I could use the Graph API 'posts' method of the 'page' object to obtain similar data, but that requires SSL and an access token, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: I believe RSS feeds are officially deprecated. They may still work for some pages, but Facebook rolls out and removes features in a staged manner depending on when the page was created.

Comment: As `2013-05`, new pages stll have an accessible RSS feed.

Comment: As of `2015-01` the `/feeds/page.php?format={...}&id={...}` link format no longer seems to work, including the link in the OP.

Comment: facebook have removed access token free access to the JSON feeds, but you can still access the RSS20 format feeds without a token, but this access method has been deprecated and will be gone in about 80 days from now.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook have changed its implementation to get facebook page RSS Feed

Following steps to get Facebook RSS Feed

- Create facebook App [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register#create-app)
- From the above App you will get client_id and client_secret and then call this url

  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=client_id_value&client_secret=client_secret_value&grant_type=client_credentials

  *Replace client_id_value and client_secret_value with its actual value*
- From the above url, you will get assess token, Pass this token in below url to get page RSS Feed

  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/1242433444/feed?access_token=access_token_value

*here 1242433444 is facebook page id*

Comment: I tried it, this doesn't work for some reason, is there a certain amount of time you have to wait after creating an facebook app? I was able to get the access token but not generate the page RSS feed.

Comment: I tried and its work for me. Please make sure your RSS Feed URL must be like https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{page-id}/feed?access_token={access-token-value}

You just only need to change {page-id} with facebook page id and {access-token-value} with token that will you get from Above mentioned URL.

Comment: @AkashJain As of 2016-04-10, this URL seems to return JSON, not RSS.

Comment: I got this error: `(#15) This method cannot be called with a client token or an app secret embedded in the client code`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Facebook prefers JSON over RSS. They support both formats to date, but JSON will likely outlive RSS. I've created some code samples for how to parse the JSON feed with PHP if you're interested:

http://liljosh.com/facebook-page-json-rss-feed/

No access token is required if the page is published (step one in the link above).

Comment: facebook have removed access token free access to the JSON feeds, you can still access the RSS20 feeds without a token, but they have been deprecated and will be gone in about 80 days from now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on the RSS feed feature.

Your best approach for machine readable data is to query the `statuses` connection, eg `https://graph.facebook.com/facebook/statuses?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`.

You can then parse the JSON and output it as RSS.

Comment: Thanks Colm for the advice.  I seem to obtain better results using the **posts** connection.  When I use **statuses**, I receive older messages in the JSON response, and they don't seem to match the RSS feed data.

Comment: Yeah, `/statuses` will only get you Status Updates from the page. `/posts` or `/feed` will get you a lot more data.

Anyway, glad it was of use.