# Embedding a Facebook Post in a web page with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the impression this is either ridiculously simple and I'm missing the point, or it's not possible.

I want to embed in a web page (using only client-side JS) the most recent post from one of a selection of Facebook pages.  The following code works, other than one problem:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
  FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    status: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.3'
  }), 
  FB.login(function(response){
      if(response.authResponse){
         var id = ['FBpage1', 'FBpage2', 'FBpage3'];
         var num = id.length;
         var rn = Math.round(Math.random()* num);
          FB.api('/' + id[rn] + '/posts?limit=1', function(apiResp){
            link = apiResp.data[0].actions[0].link;
            post = '<div class="fb-post" data-href="' + link + '" data-width="500"></div>';
            $('#container').append(post);
            FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('container'));
          });
      }
  }); 
};   
</script>
<div id = "container"> 
</div>
```

This code selects a page from the array, finds the most recent post on that page (by the page owner), and runs the standard embed FB code.  The problem is that it requires the user to be logged in to Facebook, and pops up the UI. Is there some way to find the most recent post on a page and programmatically generate the embed code without the login pop up?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest using the Facebook RSS/JSON feed as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020897/official-facebook-rss-feed-for-a-page (however, the page will need to be published so if you can't control or ask for changes to the page, it may not work).

Comment: Thanks - but that all looks to have been deprecated in favour of the graph api.

Comment: API v2 requires use of an access token for every request now (except user profile pictures) – so you can not do it client-side without having the user login first. If you do it server-side, you can use your app access token (if the page is public and unrestricted).

Comment: Thanks - I thought that was the case.